# extract PDF text by columns

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

My question is:

How can I extract text from a PDF file which is divided in columns in a way that I get the result separated by this columns?

Background:
I work on a project about text analyses (especially scientific texts). 
These texts sometimes are published in muliple column layouts with each column given a separate page number.
To order the extracted text by the layouted pagenumbers it would be useful to extract the text by columns.

---

I use **pdfBox** and tried / searched for several things:

- I tried the `getThreadBeads()` method of the `PDPage` class -> result: list with 0 size
- I tried graping the text with the `getCharactersByArticle()` method -> text not divided in columns
  (I tried this with pdf files of published texts as well as with self created .doc based files, each have a multiple column layout)

The thing is that pdfBox seems to divide the text by columns automatically:
If I set `setSortByPosition()` of a `PDFTextStripper` on true all signs of a page are set in a line without recognizing separate columns.
But if I set `setSortByPosition()` on false the stripper is doing this division.

For that I had a look to the pdfBox source code:
The crucial method is the `writePage()` method of PDFTextStripper.
Here spaces (which are not given in most pdfs) and line breaks are calculated obviously.
But I couldn't find how the Stripper is calculating the column breaks.

So the questions again:

- How is PDFTextStripper calculating column breaks?
- Are there methods in the pdfBox API to catch this / to extract the text by columns?
- Is this possible with other pdf-api?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I set setSortByPosition() of a PDFTextStripper on true all signs of a page are set in a line without recognizing separate columns. But if I set setSortByPosition() on false the stripper is doing this division.
>
> [...] How is PDFTextStripper calculating column breaks?

It isn't.

By setting `SortByPosition` to `false` you tell PDFBox to *not* try to sort the text pieces from the page content stream but to instead accept them in the order they appear.

In your document the text pieces seem to be drawn in the reading order, i.e. column by column. This is not true for all documents, and to cope with other documents PDFBox offers the option of sorting the text pieces left-to-right, top-to-bottom.

Activating that option (setting `SortByPosition` to `true`) in your document returns the text without respect to the columns.

> Are there methods in the pdfBox API to catch this / to extract the text by columns?

PDFBox does not analyze the page content to recognize columns. If you do the analysis, though, it allows you to extract text column by column if you provide the column rectangles as reguions.

Comment: thanks! So the reading order on which the text of the PDF relies is safed to the pdf document when it is created? I.e.: When I transform a .doc to a pdf the pdf (usually) safes the text in reading order? if yes: is there a method to store informations about columns when creating a PDF?

Comment: *When I transform a .doc to a pdf the pdf (usually) safes the text in reading order?* - *your* document is of that kind. And it appears a fairly natural order. But I cannot say how common that really is. You'd have to check your PDF sources anyway as they might be unusual after all... ;)

Comment: *is there a method to store informations about columns when creating a PDF?* - yes but that does not seem to have been used in your sample document, otherwise your experiments with `getThreadBeads` and `getCharactersByArticle` would have been more successful.

Comment: so how can I gurantee that this informations get stored in the pdf? - in example for word or openoffice.

Comment: *so how can I gurantee that this informations get stored in the pdf? - in example for word or openoffice* - That is a new question. Please create a new stackoverflow question on that aspect and include the appropriate *office tags for input from people more knowledgeable in those office solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Combined with @mkl's answer, I used PDFbox to complete the extraction of text by columns.

The way I find the boundary of two columns is trying constantly. =:

```
    StringBuilder pdfText = new StringBuilder();
    PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();

    stripper.setSortByPosition(true);

    Rectangle rectLeft = new Rectangle(10, 60, 320, 820);

    Rectangle rectRight = new Rectangle(330, 60, 320, 820);

    stripper.addRegion("leftColumn", rectLeft);

    stripper.addRegion("rightColumn", rectRight);

    PDPageTree allPages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages();
    int pageNumber = document.getNumberOfPages();


    String leftText = "";
    String rightText = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < pageNumber; i++) {

        PDPage page = (PDPage) allPages.get(i);

        stripper.extractRegions(page);
        leftText = stripper.getTextForRegion("leftColumn");
        rightText = stripper.getTextForRegion("rightColumn");

        pdfText.append(leftText);
        pdfText.append(rightText);


    }
```

Comment: user8955328, your solution is good. thanks for providing it. But can you suggest how can add those rectangles dynamically. To explain further, I have a scenario where these columns can be between 5 lines and 20 lines.

Comment: user1760178, I think it can be solved by adaptive learning, but I have not done it well. Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, found this solution using a different lib that worked out of the box when extracting text from one column or 2 columns pdfs.

Note this piece of code should be used for searchable pdfs and not scanned!

```
!pip install pymupdf
```

then -

```
import fitz

with fitz.open("filepath.pdf") as doc:
  for page_num, page in enumerate(doc):
      text = page.get_text()
      print(page_num)
      print(text)
```

(The enumerate in the for-loop was for my convenience only and is not necessary if you don't need the page number.)