# Extract Text from PDF Column wise, with column varying in size and position

Tags: pdf, itext, pdfbox, pdftotext

How can I extract text from a PDF file which is divided in columns in a way that I get the result separated by this columns?

These columns can be of different heights and can be spanning across multiple pages some times.

Given below is the picture of the sample PDF. This is how I need to read the text.

Each section between two black lines is a group.
In each group, 
first column can span across multiple lines
Second Column and Third Column are relevant each row wise.

I tried the solutions proposed by the links like the following. [extract PDF text by columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26233387/extract-pdf-text-by-columns) But no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The pdf is available at the following link. [Sample PDF](https://www.scribd.com/document/419494453/This-is-a-Sample-Document)

[image]

Comment: Are your pdfs tagged? Tagging has become more and more common, and text extraction with tags may well keep the structure.

Comment: @mkl They are not tagged.

Comment: Can you share an example PDF?

Comment: @mkl I have provided the sample PDF in the question. You can download it from there.

Answer (score 0):

*Your question did not mention your PDF library of choice. Your tags presented a choice of [itext](/questions/tagged/itext), [pdfbox](/questions/tagged/pdfbox), and [pdftotext](/questions/tagged/pdftotext). I chose iText 5.5.x for Java here; an analog solution should also be possible using PDFBox. I'm not sure about Pdftotext.*

Inspecting the internals of your PDF one observes:

- The text showing instructions are arranged in reading order.

  Thus, you don't need to sort them for text extraction and you can base your solution on the `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy`.
- There are numerous single white space characters shown here or there without meaning, interfering with the actual text.

  You should filter these extra space characters.
- The dataset divider lines are the only filled paths. Furthermore, these divider lines also are drawn in "reading order".

  Thus, you can already recognize them by the fill operation and do not need to analyze the path form, and right when you recognize them, you can add a marker to the text extraction strategy output.

Thus, you can implement your task by extending the `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy`:

```java
public class SimpleDividerAwareTextExtractionStrategy extends SimpleTextExtractionStrategy implements TextExtractionStrategy, ExtRenderListener {
    @Override
    public void renderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) {
        if (!" ".equals(renderInfo.getText()))
            super.renderText(renderInfo);
    }

    @Override
    public void modifyPath(PathConstructionRenderInfo renderInfo) { }

    @Override
    public Path renderPath(PathPaintingRenderInfo renderInfo) {
        if (renderInfo.getOperation() == PathPaintingRenderInfo.FILL)
            appendTextChunk("\n----------\n");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void clipPath(int rule) { }
}
```

*([SimpleDividerAwareTextExtractionStrategy](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/extract/SimpleDividerAwareTextExtractionStrategy.java#L31) helper class)*

Applying this strategy to your sample PDF:

```java
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SOURCE);
PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
SimpleDividerAwareTextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleDividerAwareTextExtractionStrategy();
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++)
    parser.processContent(i, strategy);
String content = strategy.getResultantText();

System.out.println(content);
```

*([DividerAwareTextExtraction](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/extract/DividerAwareTextExtraction.java#L108) test `testSimple419494453ThisIsASampleDocument`)*

one gets:

```
This is a sample document
----------

SAM PARTNERS LLC.
Existing Client with Premium
Support, Retail Client
123 Popsicle Ave
Candyville IA 50325
512-512-5555
Order Number Order Quantity
RTL123 45
RTL456 25
RTL324 95
RTL457 100
----------

DUNDER MIFFLIN
Existing Client with Standard
Support, Corporate Client
123 Lolipop Ave
Candyville PA 21325
215-512-5555
Order Number Order Quantity
RTL1234 400
RTL4565 200
----------

Mobile PARTNERS LLC.
New Client with Premium
Support, Retail Client
123 First Ave
Nashville TN 51325
514-512-5555
Order Number Order Quantity
RTL123 45
RTL456 25
RTL324 95
RTL457 25
RTL457 25
RTL457 25
RTL457 25
----------

BLUEBERRY MUFFIN
New Client, Corporate Client
123 STORM Ave
Hershey PA 50325
216-512-5555
Order Number Order Quantity
RTL1234 400
RTL4565 200
----------
```

To extract the datasets you merely need to find the separator string `----------` (of course you can use a different one in `SimpleDividerAwareTextExtractionStrategy`), then read all lines up to `Order Number Order Quantity` for the name and address data, and then read all lines up to the next separator string for the order information.