# How to extract text from a PDF with 2 columns

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, pypdf, pdfminer

I am trying to extract text from a PDF that has text in 2 columns (side by side). I tried with `pdfplumber` package, but it reads the pdf text line by line disrespecting columns.

Is there an easy way to extract text from such a pdf?

My sample pdf file is here: https://www.ieee-pes.org/images/files/pdf/pg4-sample-conference-paper.pdf

**Expected Behavior** (Introduction section in the above pdf):

> This template provides authors with most of the formatting specifications needed for preparing electronic versions of PES

**Actual Behavior**:

> This template provides authors with most of the formatting numbering of your graphics (figures and tables) and make sure specifications needed for preparing electronic versions of PES that all appropriate references are included.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [extract PDF text by columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26233387/extract-pdf-text-by-columns)